# Delete rows from table based on condition if other data exists within the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data returned by a query:-

```
CUSTACCOUNT     DIVISION        EXTPERSON    SALESMAN
C0001729            ECD        5637263283    Ian
C0001729            Fuel       5637369057  Peter
C0001729            Fuel       NULL        House
C0001729            ECD        NULL          House
C0001729            BSC        5637263239    Andrew
```

I would like a way to delete all rows which have null in the `EXTPERSON` column only if another row has the same `DIVISION` and `EXTPERSON` has a value, if they do not then to leave the rows in and not delete... I hope that makes sense. Is there a way to do this?

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Note that you just have to select the code and click the code-button above the editor. You don't need to use html to format it. [Read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code, assuming #ACCOUNTS has your table data

```
DELETE A FROM #ACCOUNTS A
WHERE EXTPERSON   IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #ACCOUNTS B
WHERE A.DIVISION = B.DIVISION   
AND ISNULL(B.EXTPERSON,0)<>0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query:

```
DELETE FROM t 
FROM tbl t 
WHERE 
 EXTPERSON IS NULL 
  AND EXISTS( 
   SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE t.DIVISION =DIVISION AND EXTPERSON IS NOT NULL 
   )
```

**Explanation:**

We are deleting the rows which are null and in the outer WHERE query part we check for other rows which have dame DIVISION but have value in EXTPERSON.

**Test scripts:**

```
create table tbl ( CUSTACCOUNT  nvarchar(20),DIVISION  nvarchar(20), EXTPERSON  nvarchar(20),SALESMAN nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO tbl values
 ('C0001729','ECD','5637263283','Ian')
,('C0001729','Fuel','5637369057','Peter')
,('C0001729','Fuel',       NULL,'House')
,('C0001729','ECD',        NULL,'House')
,('C0001729','BSC','5637263239','Andrew')

select * from tbl
begin transaction

DELETE FROM t 
FROM tbl t 
WHERE 
 EXTPERSON IS NULL 
  AND EXISTS( 
   SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE t.DIVISION =DIVISION AND EXTPERSON IS NOT NULL 
   )

select * from tbl
rollback transaction

drop table tbl
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks, I used to left join and check in where if I have a link.

For exemple, for a SQL struct as:

```
`a`(`id`, `type`, `val`)
```

If i want to "select only lines, ID included, that already have the same type than another"...

```
select a1.* from `a` a1 left join `a` a2 on a2.`type`=a1.`type` and a2.`id`!=a1.`id` where a2.`id` is not null;
```

Such a task may also be performed with a subquery using group by, count, having... But subqueries are. Erm. Subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from TABLE1 T1 where EXISTS
(select CUSTACCOUNT, DIVISION, EXTPERSON,SALESMAN  from TABLE2  T2

where EXTPERSON IS NULL AND  T1.DIVISION<>T2.DIVISION
) and EXTPERSON   IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data setup:

```
create table #data (CUSTACCOUNT varchar(50), DIVISION varchar(50), EXTPERSON varchar(50), SALESMAN varchar(50))
insert into #data values
    ('C0001729', 'ECD', '5637263283', 'Ian'),
    ('C0001729', 'Fuel', '5637369057', 'Peter'),
    ('C0001729', 'Fuel', NULL, 'House'),
    ('C0001729', 'ECD', NULL, 'House'),
    ('C0001729', 'BSC', '5637263239', 'Andrew'),
    ('C0001729', 'SomeOther', NULL, 'Name')
```

Delete query:

```
;with aData
as (
    select
        rn = row_number() over (partition by DIVISION order by EXTPERSON desc),
        cntExt = count(EXTPERSON) over (partition by DIVISION)
    from #data
)
delete from aData
where rn > cntExt and cntExt > 0
```

Check table data:

```
select * from #data
```

Output:

```
CUSTACCOUNT  DIVISION    EXTPERSON   SALESMAN
------------ ----------- ----------- ----------
C0001729     ECD         5637263283  Ian
C0001729     Fuel        5637369057  Peter
C0001729     BSC         5637263239  Andrew
C0001729     SomeOther   NULL        Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete delTable 
  from table delTable 
  join table hasValue
        on delTable.EXTPERSON is null 
       and hasValue.EXTPERSON is not null 
       and delTable.DIVISION = hasValue.DIVISION
```